# Making a cookie accessible in localhost?

Tags: jsp, servlets, cookies

I am using a server in local host in jboss. the server is deployed in abc.war. I access the files in the server with path `eg http://localhost:8080/abc/​hello.jsp` . Now I want ot set a cookie  which is accessible anywhere within abc. how to do that.

Answer (score -1):

Set the path of the cookie appropriately

```
javax.servlet.http.Cookie.setPath(String) - This cookie should be presented only with requests beginning with this URL.
```

http://www.roseindia.net/jsp/jspcookies.shtml

Comment: I set the path appropriately but the cookies are not accesible from all the tabs in firefox and googl chrome.However it is accessible  from all the tabs in internet explorer

Comment: The cookie is something stored in the browser, so it won't be in another browser unless you created the cookie there too. There are a couple of extensions for Firefox with which you can check what the current cookie looks like, such as this one: https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/view-cookies/

Comment: Obviously cookies are not shared between browsers. you are not trying to understand my question.

Comment: What path is it stored with, in the browser?

Comment: The cookies has access to the whole doamain.